# The liaison with « plus »

Tags: prononciation

In a sentence like « plus on fait quelque chose...» is the liaison necessary? Originally my dictionary states "plus/le plus used in comparison (meaning more/the most) is pronounced [ply] before a consonant and [plyz] before a vowel" meaning the liaison is compulsory but today on French radio I heard someone speaking who sounded native and did not make the liaison so I just wanted to double check to see if it is necessary or does it change between differents parts of France?

Comment: @None, it doesn't tell me whether the liaison itself is optional, could you clarify that?

Comment: It says "In this case, the s is rarely sounded (liaisons excepted)".  It is a case of compulsory liaison. Liaison is compulsory after a short adverb. For example see [here](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm) or [here](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-117459.php). Maybe you're right this could have been answered, but anyway now you've got your answer. Sorry.

Comment: @None Yeah no problem, I understand now